# what does the error “Exception in template helper: Error: Handler with name 'pathFinder' already exists.” mean?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

My code is

```
Template.homeItem.helpers({
  'shareData': function() {
  return {
title: this.title,
 author:Meteor.users.findOne(this.createdBy),//createdBy stores the author's userId
url:  Router.map(function(){
Router.route('/content/:_id',{
name:'pathFinder',
template:'pathFinder',
data: function(){
  var currentRoute= this.params._id;
  return contentsList.findOne({_id: currentRoute});
  }});})}}
```

I do not know about the correct way to pass url in shareData of shareit.

Thanking Everyone

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please properly indent your code. It's very unreadable as it is and it contains error due to poor indentation.

To your question; It means that you have already created a route with that name.

It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve but I think you are trying to to do something like this:

```
Template.homeItem.helpers({
  'shareData': function() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      author: Meteor.users.findOne(this.createdBy),
      url: '/content/' + this._id
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Sorry i was busy the whole day.
Now the error is not showing in console but the url is not getting roted to after i click on "Share on Facebook" link.
I do not know the right way to pass the url in shareData function.
Thanking you for answering

Comment: Can you show me the right way to pass the url in shareData of shareit

Comment: From looking at the [docs](https://atmospherejs.com/joshowens/shareit), I think you misunderstood what the `url` parameter does. It doesn't redirect the user. It simply sets that URL as the URL to be shared.

Comment: But still it is taking the current page url only. I am unable to find the solution, it has hit a dead end